# Why 1px width line looks different when it has different left number?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why these two lines' width are different?  They are both supposed to 1px;

The only difference is they have different left number, but why this cause the width change?

By the way, my chrome version is 84.0.4147.105  (win10), and in firefox it looks correct.

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
      }
      .demo {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: yellow;

      }
      .line, .line2 {
        left: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        background-color: red;
        height: 500px;
      }
      .line2 {
        left: 402px;
       }
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it could just be a quirk of the browser. It doesn't look that way in the snippet for me and I'm using Chrome

Comment: No repro either, latest firefox

Comment: Chrome Explorer? Do you mean Google Chrome? What version are you using?

Comment: My chrome version is  84.0.4147.105   , os is windows

Comment: Maybe because you are using a background color for a 1px large element, that made a rendering problem, try changing `.line, .line2 {
            left: 300px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            border-right: 1px solid red;
            height: 500px;
          }` to use a border instead

Comment: @SaymoinSam I tried border left and right instead of width, still has the same issue.

Comment: And still only one line has the problem?!

Comment: As you anybody interested to know - recently I've got a bug, when in a flex container I've got a 1px width divs. Several of the divs looked bolder although on inspect, their width was 1px. It seems to be related to display flex. So even when width was set in px, the browser somethimes displays elements differently.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found because I zoomed the chrome to 125% then it cause the problem

by the way, I tried zoom to 125% in Firefox and it's still shows correct.

thanks everyone.